# tableView not reusing cell properly

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

This is my code for a tableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CounterCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CounterCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = nibLoadedCell2;
    }

    Program *program = [memory getProgramAtIndex:[memory chosenProgram]];
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfIntervals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    arrayOfIntervals = program.arrayOfIntervals;
    NSMutableDictionary *interval = [arrayOfIntervals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    UITextField *intervalName = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    intervalName.text = [interval objectForKey:@"nameOfInterval"];
    [intervalName addTarget:self action:@selector(returnKey:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
    [intervalName addTarget:self action:@selector(editingEnded:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
    [intervalName addTarget:self action:@selector(editTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];

    timeInSeconds = [[interval objectForKey:@"timeInSeconds"] intValue];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        firstCellGeneralTime = timeInSeconds;
    }

    NSString *time = [self timeTextWithTimeInSeconds:timeInSeconds];

    UILabel *intervalTime = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    intervalTime.text = time;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        majorLabel.text = time;
    }

    UILabel *hourString = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:11];
    hourString.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",hoursInt];

    UILabel *minuteString = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:12];
    minuteString.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",minutesInt];

    UILabel *secondString = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:13];
    secondString.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",secondsInt];



    UIButton *editTime = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:21];
    [editTime addTarget:self action:@selector(openPicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];




    return cell;
}
```

My table view shows a bit less than 3 cells, and on a certain point i delete the first cell and than the 4th cell is showing up.

The problem is that the 4th cell is exactly like my 3rd cell, although it should be different.

It does reuse it as it should.

I don't know what i've done wrong.

This is the code for the deletion of a cell:

```
NSIndexPath *firstCellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
NSArray *arrayOfIndexPath = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstCellIndexPath, nil];
[atableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:arrayOfIndexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

Comment: what is `nibLoadedCell2 `

Comment: The custom cell i'm using

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the first `interval` from the `program.arrayOfIntervals` array while deleting the cell.

Comment: I am removing it from the arrayOfIntervals. Otherwise it would have crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, the problematic code is:

```
Program *program = [memory getProgramAtIndex:[memory chosenProgram]];
NSMutableArray *arrayOfIntervals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
arrayOfIntervals = program.arrayOfIntervals;
NSMutableDictionary *interval = [arrayOfIntervals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I am creating a new program and get the details of the intervals from it, instead of using the program i removed the first interval from…

I feel so dumb...

Comment: Delete arrayOfIntervals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; from your code. You are allocating an array but then immediately setting the variable to something else.